# Trouble using lxml from a .py file. It works with the interpreter

Tags: python, lxml

I have python.org v2.7 installed on my Snow Leopard. There's also a Apple 2.6 Python onboard. I pip installed lxml with the 'sudo pip install lxml' command. I made sure I was doing this from within the bin directory of my python.org 2.7 version.

When I give the command:

```
from lxml import etree
```

within the IDLE interpreter everything works as expected and I can go on an use all the lxml methods. However if I create a .py file with a single line:

```
from lxml import etree
```

and I try to run it (be it within IDLE RUN/F5 or via command line '$python testlxml.py') I get the error: ImportError: cannot import name etree

The same holds true if I try importing other lxml modules like 'from lxml import html', it will work wonders in the interpreter but it won't in a .py file. I googled around but could not find a solution to this specific issue. Anybody got a clue? Thanks!

Comment: Just so you're clear, try `import sys; print sys.version` from each environment to make sure you're running the version you think you're running.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I followed your advice and I can now verify that both interpreter and py are run by Python 2.7.1. This is becoming quite intriguing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out. There was a file named lxml.py in the PATH which wasn't the lxml module. Actually, I created that file when I started playing with the lxml tutorial a couple days ago and didn't pay attention to the filename match. I totally forgot about it. Dumb me.

Answer (score 1):

Which interpreter are they running with?

Make sure the first line of your py file is

```
#!/full/path/to/python2.7
```

Comment: Thank you Richo, I did that but the issue is still there.

Comment: I'm confused, in your question you put that $python testxml.py fails..

Can you put up the results of $python2.7 testsml.py ? The only other thing I can think of is if you have a .pythonrc or PYTHON relevant environment variables that are interfering. Can you try it with an empty environment.